# Customize the color of frame's section head/foot, including Page Number, in Cambridge template

Tags: beamer

I would like to change to my favorite Green color (of the svgnames package) the default color of the frame's section head and foot (I don't know what it's exactly called, but basically it's where presenters often put his name, seminar name/venue, dates, and page number, both on top and at bottom of the frame. Specifically, in the frames which will be shown if the code is run, how can I customize the two following?

(1) How to convert "First results" as shown in ``Section in Head" from WHITE color to Green color (Green color of svgnames)?

(2) How to convert the PAGE NUMBER from DEFAULT Maroon-looking or Brown-looking number to Green to be consistent with GREEN color?

I'm a rather inexperienced Beamer user. Could you please help?

```
\documentclass [xcolor=svgnames, t] {beamer} 
\usepackage[round,sort&compress,authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{booktabs, comment} 
\usepackage[absolute, overlay]{textpos} 
%%% Beamer them customization
\useoutertheme{infolines} 
\usetheme{CambridgeUS} % I like this them but want to customize it a bit
\usecolortheme[named=Green]{structure} % I want this color, etc.
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black} % Control text color
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=Green} % Color of slide title
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=Green,bg=Green!0} 
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=Green}
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{bg=Green}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{} 
\setbeamertemplate{items}[circle] 
\newenvironment{reference}[2]{ %
\begin{textblock*} {\textwidth} (#1, #2) 
\footnotesize\it\bgroup\color{red!50!black}} {\egroup\end{textblock*}}
\usepackage[]{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{colorlinks=True, linkcolor=white, citecolor=Green, urlcolor=blue, pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1.73}, pdfcreator={}, pdfauthor={}, pdftitle={}, bookmarksopenlevel=1} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% STARTING! %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title[\textcolor{Green}{My Seminar Here}] {Presentation Title}
\subtitle[]{\textcolor{black}{\scriptsize }} % Nice consistent color: Maroon
\author[\textcolor{white}{My Name Here}]
    {
        \small Author 1's Name\inst{\dagger}\\ 
        \and Author 2's Name \inst{\dagger}\\ 
        \and Author 3's Name\inst{\S} \\ 
        \and Author 4's Name\inst{\P} \\ 
        \and Author 5's Name\inst{\dagger} 
    }
\institute[]
    {
        \inst{\dagger} \scriptsize University 1 \and 
        \inst{\S} \scriptsize University 2 \and 
        \inst{\P} \scriptsize University 3
       } 

\date[\textcolor{Green}{\today}]{Place, 201X}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame} [plain] \label{titlepage}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}     
    \section{Outlines} 
        \begin{frame}{Outline}  
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item First
                \item Second
                \item Third
                \item Fourth
                \item Fifth
                \item Conclusions
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{frame}

    \section{Results} 
    \subsection{First results}

    Two things I can't figure out how to do:

    \begin{itemize}
        \item   How to convert "First results" as shown in ``Section in Head" from WHITE color to Green color (Green color of svgnames)?
        \item How to convert the PAGE NUMBER from DEFAULT Maroon-looking or Brown-looking number to Green to be consistent with GREEN color?
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Crosspost info: [Customize color of frame's section head/foot](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=61&t=28641).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for are the two statements:

```
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{bg=Green, fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{date in head/foot}{fg=Green}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=svgnames,t] {beamer} 

\useoutertheme{infolines} 
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme[named=Green]{structure}

\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{bg=Green}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=Green}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{bg=Green, fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{date in head/foot}{fg=Green}


\begin{document}

  \section{Results} 
  \subsection{First results}

    \begin{frame}
        Two things I can't figure out how to do:

        \begin{itemize}
            \item   How to convert "First results" as shown in ``Section in Head" from WHITE color to Green color (Green color of svgnames)?
            \item How to convert the PAGE NUMBER from DEFAULT Maroon-looking or Brown-looking number to Green to be consistent with GREEN color?
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Off topic comments:

- You don't need `\usepackage[]{hyperref}`, beamer already loads the package. In fact it is better to not load it a second time, as this has the risk for option clashes.
- Don't use formatting commands in macros such as `\title`. If you want the title to be green in the footline, use

  ```
  \setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{fg=Green}
  ```

  same for author, institute, date etc. (that was the error why the framenumbers had the wrong colour)
- `Two things...` has to be placed inside a frame.